# How to pass startup options to the XServer on 18.04?

Tags: keyboard, xorg, startup

I am using Ubuntu desktop 18.04 with the i3 window manager. I would like to change the keyboard key repeat rate using seat-defaults as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408461/where-is-the-default-repeat-rate-for-xset-stored). I don't want to use `xset`, because it has to be re-run every time I plug in an external keyboard.

While the file `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc` exists on my system, adding the suggested parameters `-ardelay 300 -arinterval 25` does not result in any changes after reboot. So where can I add them instead?

Comment: In dconf Editor and check /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/repeat-interval.

Comment: Works great in gnome sessions, but sadly not in i3.

Comment: Did you find a solution @quappas ?